# Deleting multiple tasks in IntelliJ 11

Tags: intellij-idea

I have many unused tasks which I would like to delete, but can't find any good way do it beside deleting them one by one. I can see in intelliJ 12 [help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-deleting-tasks.html#procedure%0A______to_delete_a_taskdeleting_tasks), that you can do multiple selection of tasks and delete them, but that doesn't seem to work in IntelliJ 11.

Will it be safe to delete all the tasks from the workspace.xml file? I can see all my tasks there but not their contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove them by selecting the task from the task dropdown, hovering ove the task to be deleted, and then selecting the right arrow key (yes, this could be made easier).

Once done you should have 2 options:

- Switch to
- Remove

The remove option will (obviously) delete the task.

[image: Task Removal]

I hope that this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks, but doing this for 100 tasks will be tedious work :) I'm looking for some kind of batch delete.

Comment: :-) Ah, ok - you did say that (cant read!). In that case editing the workspace.xml is your best bet - its pretty safe to do (but I'd make a backup, just in case).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the how to. You can do multiple selection and delete all of them in one go.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/deleting-tasks.html

Comment: This is an IntelliJ 12 feature and not possible in IntelliJ 11.